# I am getting a 400 status code error, from the server. The server is working fine

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios

My client and server are setup locally right now. I am trying to register a user. Basically my server is working fine, as i checked using postman. The problem is, when I send the register request the server returns, 400 status code. This usually means there is an error in the client. I think there is an error in the headers.

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const register = newUser => {
    return axios
        .post('api/register', newUser, {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}

export const login = user => {
    return axios
        .post(
            'api/login',
            {
                email: user.email,
                password: user.password
            },
            {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            }
        )
        .then(response => {
            localStorage.setItem('usertoken', response.data.token)
            return response.data.token
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}

export const getProfile = () => {
    return axios
        .get('api/profile', {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.usertoken}` }
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            return response.data
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}
```

Comment: Not quite enough information to help I think. Usually a `400` means our request is malformed. Are you sure the `newUser` object looks like what the server expects?

Comment: I solved the error. Yeah actually the newUser object format was wrong. Anyways thanks!